# SQL Server CE Connection - Fully Qualified Path

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am trying to establish the data source for my SQL Server CE connection without a fully qualified path.

At the moment I have:

```
using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"data source=C:\Users\owenna\Documents\My Web Sites\TheatreBooking\App_Data\TheatreBooking.sdf"))
```

Which works perfectly well to access the database in `TheatreBooking.sdf`, however, I am looking to make the URL shorter, so that if somebody who did not have the same path, but were to open from a zip file that had the path

```
My Web Sites\TheatreBooking\App_Data\TheatreBooking.sdf
```

that it would still work without having to be fully qualified.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get local specific documents path using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```